# Return value as bool from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, boolean

Trying to write multi scripts that would access one text file to retrieve their toggle values from the said text file and then return with a value as false and change it to true and vice versa.

Value always comes back as false, not sure what I'm missing but here is the text file:

```
1
False
3
True
5
6
7
8
9
```

Here is the source code:

```
def append():
  with open('values', 'r') as file:
      # read a list of lines into data
      data = file.readlines()
  # now change the line
  re_value = value

  data[1] = re_value+"\n"
  # and write everything back
  with open('values', 'w') as file:
      file.writelines(data)
  print("value changed to "+re_value)

def read() -> bool:
  #opens the value file to find the value of the toggle
  f=open("values", "r")

  for x, line in enumerate(f):
      if x == 1:
          toggle = line
          print(toggle)
          return toggle
  f.close()


toggle = read()

if toggle:
    print("Light is on turn it off")
    #runs command to turn off the light
    #runs command to change value for light
    value = "False"
    append()
else:
    print("Light is off turn it on")
    #runs command to turn on the light
    #runs command to change value for light
    value = "True"
    append()
```

Comment: Can you please update the question with proper indentation?

Comment: please edit your question with correct indentation and we will try and help

Comment: Will do that now

Comment: Is that better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the boolean value you are using to evaluate the condition is a string.

In this case you could keep it as string:

```
if value == "True":
    print "Condition is true!"
```

Or implement something similar:

```
def str2bool(v):
  return v.lower() in ("true",) # you can add to the tuple other values that you consider as true if useful

print str2bool(value)
```

Comment: For some strange reason even if I run it as you suggested with if value== "True" it always comes back false...or skips to the else statement

Comment: Added the new line tag to the answer and it worked perfectly thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this to toggle:

```
putback=[]
with open('values', 'r') as file:
    for e in file.readlines():
        if e=='True' or e=='False':
            print(e)
            putback.append(not e)
        else:
            putback.append(e)
with open('values','w') as file1:
     file.write('\n'.join(putback))
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake guys, thank you for the help, changed the if statement to

```
if toggle=="True\n":
    print("Light is on turn it off")
    #runs command to turn off the light
    #runs command to change value for light
    value = "False"
    append()
```

it was missing the new line tag as it is a multiline text document

Answer (score 0):

From what i can understand you want to change True as False and False as True and leave the rest as it is.

```
final_output = []
with open("values") as file:
    data = file.readlines()

for line in data:
    line = eval(line.strip())
    if isinstance(line, bool):
        print("Value is {0} Changing to {1}".format(line, not line))
        final_output.append(not line)
    else:
        final_output.append(line)

with open("values", 'w') as file:
    file.write("\n".join([str(line) for line in final_output]))
```